# Como utilizar uma variável no array_walk?

Tags: php, array

Estou tentando uma solução sem percorrer "manualmente"(`foreach`) um array, para adicionar nos subarrays, um novo par de `chave => valor`. Com o `array_walk` posso invocar um callback e tratar o array mas como passo uma variável para o callback dele?

O array possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'abc'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'def'
    ]
];
```

Tentei adicionar os novos pares da seguinte maneira:

```
array_walk($array, function ($v, $k) { $v['token'] = $token; });
```

Porém recebo um `Undefined variable` mesmo com ela declarada e com valor atribuído.

Utilizando a key `use` na função de `callback`, ele não adiciona a nova chave:

```
function ($v, $k) use ($token) { $v['token'] = $token; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) diz que ao se utilizar `array_walk()` apenas os valores serão alterandos por padrão ou seja a estrutura não será alterada. Quando callback não respeitar essa regra o comportamenta da função pode ser indefinido ou imprevisível.

> Only the values of the array may potentially be changed; its structure cannot be altered, i.e., the programmer cannot add, unset or reorder elements. If the callback does not respect this requirement, the behavior of this function is undefined, and unpredictable.

Devido a essa restrição, acredito que seja mais confiável usar `array_map()` que gera um parecido, `array_walk()` altera o array de entranda enquanto `array_map()` não o que ele faz é devolver um novo com as alterações.

```
$arr = array_map(function($item) use ($token){$item['novo'] = $token;  return $item; } , $array);
```

Com `array_walk()` você pode passar dois argumentos na função anônima, o primeiro o item atual do array que **deve ser passado como referência** e o segundo o valor (`$token`)

```
$token = 2015;
array_walk($array, function(&$item) use ($token){ $item['novo'] = $token; });
```